# ArangoDB How can I use methods in the @arangodb namespace in a Node/Express app?

Tags: node.js, arangodb

I am trying to use the database methods like `db._databases()` or `db._name()` in a node app.

The manual shows `require("@arangodb").db._name();` which works fine from arangosh but when I try to `require('@arangodb')` in the app, node throws

> Error: Cannot find module '@arangodb'.

Attempting to install from NPM results in an error that it is not in the NPM registry.

So how can one require that namespace? Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I'm running the current 3.4rc in a docker container in case this makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@arangodb` module can not be required in Node.js. It works in ArangoDB's V8 environment only. It is available in arangosh, Foxx, JS transactions and user-defined AQL functions.

If you want to talk to ArangoDB from a JavaScript environment like Node.js or a browser, then use the [official JavaScript driver **arangojs**](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Drivers/JS/). Note that its interface is different from the one provided by the [`@arangodb` module](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Appendix/JavaScriptModules/ArangoDB.html).

Comment: I was modifying the example from the Node tutorial from the arango website which does a "db = require('arangojs')(); to include the official JS driver and succeeds in calling db.createDatabase('newDB') and db.useDatabase('newDB'). Calling db._name() afterwards results in "TypeError: db._name is not a function" even switching back to the systemDB with db.useDatabase('_system');. I tracked this down to what I thought was the @arangodb namespace missing but being new to the whole Node environment I may very well be wrong. How can you get a list of databases or the name of the current DB in node?

Comment: With `db.get()` and `db.listDatabases()`, see here: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Drivers/JS/Reference/Database/DatabaseManipulation.html#databaseget

Comment: Actually `(await db.get()).name` if you only want the name of the database (there are also the `id`, `path` and `isSystem` attribute). `db.listDatabases()` returns an array of strings with the database names. If you want to try this in Node interactively, you may need to do: `var db = require('arangojs')(); (async function() { console.dir( await db.get() ) })()`

Comment: You are welcome. If this solves your problem, please accept and up-vote the answer. Thanks!